# PHP Vcalendar: plain text description visible instead of html text

Tags: php, html, outlook-2007, vcalendar

I'm working on sending meeting invitations through php. My code does send a meeting invite (which is visible to end users as a meeting invite) however I'm unable to set html description.

I suspect the problem could be because of me using string variable to pass argument to `X-ALT-DESC`. In the invite, plain-text is visible which I set through `DESCRIPTION` tag however HTML text is not. If the invite is received by an Outlook 2007 he should see the HTML text right?

Here is the code:

```
$aHeaders = array();
$aHeaders[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$aHeaders[] = 'Content-Type: text/calendar; method=REQUEST';
$aHeaders[] = 'Content-Class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage';
$aHeaders[] = 'From: abc@xyz.com';
$aHeaders[] = 'Reply-To: abc@xyz.com';
$sHeaders = implode("\r\n", $aHeaders);

  $sBody .=  "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\n";
  $sBody .=  "PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 12.0 MIMEDIR//EN\r\n";
  $sBody .=  "VERSION:2.0\r\n";
  $sBody .=  "METHOD:REQUEST\r\n";
  $sBody .=  "X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE\r\n";
  $sBody .=  "BEGIN:VEVENT\r\n";
  $sBody .=  "ATTENDEE:mailto:" . $sTo . "\r\n";
  $sBody .=  "ORGANIZER;CN=ABC:mailto:ABC@XYZ.com\r\n";
  $sBody .=  "DTSTAMP:'.date('Ymd').'T'.date('His').'Z''\r\n";
  $sBody .=  "DTSTART:" . $sConfstart . "\r\n";
  $sBody .=  "DTEND:" . $sConfend . "\r\n";
  $sBody .=  "LOCATION:Conference Call\r\n";
  $sBody .=  "TRANSP:OPAQUE\r\n";
  $sBody .=  "SEQUENCE:0\r\n";
  $sBody .=  "UID:'. md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)) .'\r\n";
  $sBody .=  "SUMMARY:" . $sSubject . "\r\n";
  $sBody .=  "PRIORITY:5\r\n";
  $sBody .=  "CLASS:PUBLIC\r\n";
  $sBody .=  "DESCRIPTION:this is plain desc"\r\n";
  $sBody .=  "X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN\"><HTML><BODY>html goes here</BODY></HTML>\r\n";
  $sBody .=  "END:VEVENT\r\n";
  $sBody .=  "END:VCALENDAR\r\n";
```

----EDIT 
here is the generated iCalendar string

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 12.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;CN="Test_DM@xyz.com, test1@xyz.com";RSVP=TRUE:mail
    to:Test_DM@xyz.com\, test1@xyz.com
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20140222T144724Z
DESCRIPTION:this is plain desc
DTEND:20140223T140000Z
DTSTAMP:20140222T144640Z
DTSTART:20140223T130000Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20140222T144724Z
LOCATION:Conference Call
ORGANIZER;CN="test_org":mailto:test_org@xyz.com
PRIORITY:5
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:
TRANSP:OPAQUE
UID:20140222T144640Z
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//E
    N">\n<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="MS Exchange Server ve
    rsion 08.00.0681.000">\n<TITLE></TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY>\n<!-- Converted f
    rom text/plain format -->\n\n<P><FONT SIZE=2>&lt\;!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC &qu
    ot\;-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN&quot\;&gt\;&lt\;HTML&gt\;&lt\;BODY&gt\;html g
    oes here&lt\;/BODY&gt\;&lt\;/HTML&gt\;</FONT>\n</P>\n\n</BODY>\n</HTML>
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:TENTATIVE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: can you post the generated `iCalendar` string instead of the code?

Comment: i have added icalendar string just now......thx for taking a look at that :)

Comment: I don't have Outlook to test, but the DESCRIPTION field also contains HTML instead of plain text...

Comment: it must hv been a mistake....i will correct that.....but the prob remains the same :(

Comment: Well as I don't have Outlook, try to export an event from your Outlook calendar, and take a look at what they do.

Comment: thx for taking a look at my question mb21......i did compare it and the prob is with property of X-ALT-DESC. My code passed following tag: <!-- Converted from text/plain format -->. When I checked .ics file of an actual meeting invite. It has this code: <!-- Converted from text/rtf format -->.

Comment: It worked only for Indian users for some reason....didn't work for French users :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm years late, but for all those people finding this in a search result...this is not "THE" answer, but it is an answer that works for Outlook.

I was not able to get HTML to work using the X-ALT-DESC, etc., either and I'd still love to see someone answer that question.  However, you can get the HTML to be part of the event in Outlook by creating a `multipart/alternative` email.  However, again, while this works for Outlook, other services (e.g. Gmail) will only show the summary/descriptions inside the event.

> Warning: this does nothing to prevent header-injection, please use responsibly
>   ;-)

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
    //CONFIGURE HERE
    $fromName           = "John Doe";
    $fromEmail          = "john.doe@example.com";
    $toName             = "Your Name";
    $toEmail            = 'yourname@example.com';
    $start              = new DateTime('2017-08-15 15:00');
    $end                = new DateTime('2017-08-15 16:00');
    $summary            = "Hello World Event";
    //END CONFIGURATION

    $uid                = "0123456789";
    $headers            = array();
    $boundary           = "_CAL_" . uniqid("B",true) . "_B_";
    $headers[]          = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
    $headers[]          = "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"".$boundary."\"";
    $headers[]          = "To: \"{$toName}\" <{$toEmail}>";
    $headers[]          = "From: \"{$fromName}\" <{$fromEmail}>";

    $calendarLines      = array(
        "BEGIN:VCALENDAR",
        "METHOD:REQUEST",
        "PRODID:-//PHP//MeetingRequest//EN",
        "VERSION:2.0",
        "BEGIN:VEVENT",
        "ORGANIZER;CN={$fromName}:MAILTO:{$fromEmail}",
        "ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN={$toName}:MAILTO:{$toEmail}",
        "DESCRIPTION:{$summary}",
        "SUMMARY:{$summary}",
        "DTSTART:".$start->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'))->format('Ymd\THis\Z'),
        "DTEND:".$end->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'))->format('Ymd\THis\Z'),
        "UID:{$uid}",
        "CLASS:PUBLIC",
        "PRIORITY:5",
        "DTSTAMP:".gmdate('Ymd\THis\Z'),
        "TRANSP:OPAQUE",
        "STATUS:CONFIRMED",
        "SEQUENCE:0",
        "LOCATION:123 Any Street",
        "BEGIN:VALARM",
        "ACTION:DISPLAY",
        "DESCRIPTION:REMINDER",
        "TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT15M",
        "END:VALARM",
        "END:VEVENT",
        "END:VCALENDAR"
    );


    $calendarBase64     = base64_encode(implode("\r\n",$calendarLines));
    //ensure we don't have lines longer than 70 characters for older computers:
    $calendarResult     = wordwrap($calendarBase64,68,"\n",true);

    $emailLines = array(
        "--{$boundary}",
        "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso - 8859 - 1\"",
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable",
        "",
        "<html><body>",
        "<h1>Hello World</h1>",
        "<p>This is a calendar event test</p>",
        "</body></html>",
        "",
        "--{$boundary}",
        "Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=\"utf - 8\"; method=REQUEST",
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64",
        "",
        $calendarResult,
        "",
        "--{$boundary}--"
    );
    $emailContent   = implode("\n",$emailLines);

    $headersResult      = implode("\n",$headers);
    mail($toEmail, $summary, $emailContent, $headersResult );
    echo("<pre>".htmlentities($headersResult)."\n\n".htmlentities($emailContent)."</pre>");
    echo("<br /><br />");
    echo("<pre>".base64_decode($calendarResult)."</pre>");
```